# Putting graphic into UserForm in VBA

Tags: vba

I am trying to put a graphic file into a UserForm Image in VBA.  Using the code below

```
UserForm1.Image1.Picture = "d:\Missionary\Mexico\Daisy Marlene Olivares.bmp"
```

I get the error

> "Compile Error: Type mismatch".

I know that the file path is correct.
Modifying the code to the following

```
UserForm1.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture("d:\Missionary\Mexico\Daisy Marlene Olivares.bmp")
```

I get the error

> "Compile Error: Sub or Function not defined"

I suspect that part of the reason for this error is because the image control is not ActiveX.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference OLE Automation for the `LoadPicture` function.

[image]

[image]